# The constructor AddPatron(String, String) is undefined

Tags: java

I'm trying to create these commands and I get an error when creating the `AddPatron`

```
if (cmd.equals("addbook")) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Title: ");
            String title = br.readLine();
            System.out.print("Author: ");
            String author = br.readLine();
            System.out.print("Publication Year: ");
            String publicationYear = br.readLine();
            return new AddBook(title, author, publicationYear);

        } else if (cmd.equals("addpatron")) {
            BufferedReader brr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Name: ");
            String name = brr.readLine();
            System.out.print("Phone: ");
            String phone = brr.readLine();
            return new AddPatron(name, phone);
```

---

```
Error: The constructor AddPatron(String, String) is undefined
```

It says to add constructors, however I have already done this exactly the way of `AddBook`. However the only difference is the `AddPatron` class has 2 extra `Strings` which I haven't included that I want to read in.

```
public class AddPatron implements Command {

    private final String name;
    private final String phone;
    private final String id;
    private final String list_of_books_borrowed;

    public AddPatron(String name, String phone, String id, String list_of_books_borrowed){
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.id = id;
        this.list_of_books_borrowed = list_of_books_borrowed;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the compiler tells you that there is no constructor taking two strings as argument, then it means there is no such constructor. So create it, or fix the code in order to call one of the constructors which exist.

Comment: Pass in null values for the last two constructor parameters, then. You can't just omit parameters whenever you feel like it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Do you really have a class named `AddPatron`? Or is `AddPatron()` a method?

Comment: Show the `AddPatron` class. The error is self explanatory: You don't have a constructor there that accepts 2 strings as parameters

Comment: Note that classes represent *things* and their names should generally be nouns, for example `Book` or `Patron`. On the other hand methods are *actions* and their names should be verbs. So you can have a method named `addPatron()` but you should name your class just `Patron`.

Comment: edited ^^, it is created in a seperate package and is linked

Comment: Tip add: @JBNizet or whoever you're replying to, so they get notified of your response

Comment: According to your code, it seems like this is what @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas said in his comment or create a new constructor that only accepts 2 parameters

Answer (score 1):

```
public AddPatron(String name, String phone, String id, String list_of_books_borrowed)
```

This constructor requires 4 different strings.

```
new AddPatron(name, phone);
```

But here, you only pass 2 strings. You need to pass the other two or write a new constructor that only accepts the name and phone.

Note that classes represent *things* and their names should generally be nouns. On the other hand methods are *actions* and their names should be verbs. So you can have a method named `addPatron()` and a class named `Patron`. Naming a class `AddPatron` can be confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Code-Apprentice however this is part of classwork and the code was written by my teacher

Comment: Also like @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas shall i pass 2 null arguments in the constructor?

Comment: @KaziIlyas and how does it prevent you from passing 4 strings to the constructor?

Comment: @JBNizet i dont understand what u mean

Comment: The fact that your teacher wrote the code doesn't change anything to the way Java works. If a constructor takes 4 strings as arguments, you must pass it 4 strings. Not 2. If you think the last two strings should be null, then pass null. If you think they should be something else, then pass something else. If you realize that you should in fact ask the user to enter the id and the list_of_books_borrowed, then do that.

Comment: @KaziIlyas Did your teacher provide all of the code you posted here? Are you required to make any modifications to it? The code you have shown is broken since it won't compile. I suggest you talk with your teacher about it to find out what they expect.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok, i understand the last 2 strings are not required as they are not for the user to input, so i assume i will pass null values into it. Thanks

Comment: @Code-Apprentice this is a small portion of the code, i will be making modifications to it